# How to explain the go routine as callback function in this example code

Tags: go

I am confusing the following code, I didn't see the *1st* go routine has any returns in **TimelineItemStream** function, and 2nd go routine call the **unsub**. In **Subscriber** interface define the **unsub** callbackup function.

the code is come from **git clone https://github.com/nicolasparada/nakama.git**

```golang
// TimelineItem model
type TimelineItem struct {
    ID     string `json:"id"`
    UserID string `json:"-"`
    PostID string `json:"-"`
    Post   *Post  `json:"post,omitempty"`
}

// Subscriber interface.
type Subscriber interface {
    Sub(topic string, cb func(data []byte)) (unsub func() error, err error)
}

func (s *Service) TimelineItemStream(ctx context.Context) (<-chan TimelineItem, error) {
    uid, ok := ctx.Value(KeyAuthUserID).(string)
    if !ok {
        return nil, ErrUnauthenticated
    }

    tt := make(chan TimelineItem)
    unsub, err := s.pubsub.Sub(timelineTopic(uid), func(data []byte) {
        go func(r io.Reader) {
            var ti TimelineItem
            err := gob.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&ti)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("could not gob decode timeline item: %v\n", err)
                return
            }

            tt <- ti
        }(bytes.NewReader(data))
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not subscribe to timeline: %w", err)
    }

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        if err := unsub(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("could not unsubcribe from timeline: %v\n", err)
            // don't return
        }

        close(tt)
    }()

    return tt, nil
}
```

In the block of call

```golang
 unsub, err := s.pubsub.Sub(timelineTopic(uid), func(data []byte) {
        go func(r io.Reader) {
            var ti TimelineItem
            err := gob.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&ti)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("could not gob decode timeline item: %v\n", err)
                return
            }

            tt <- ti
        }(bytes.NewReader(data))
    })
```

**s.pubsub.Sub** returns a callback function, but in this block go routine has not any return , how to explain the block of code

Comment: You seem to be confused about terminology. Goroutines don't have returns. Goroutines are not functions. Goroutines execute functions.

Comment: if you think that this code is causing you a problem, then state what the problem is...

Comment: Yes. I am confused that where is the `unsub` callback function come from.